# Gnome-Shell-Extensions not installing properly

Tags: 16.04, gnome, gnome-shell-extension

I am trying to install gnome shell extensions. However after installing either `gnome-shell-extensions` or `chrome-gnome-shell`, the extensions tab in gnome tweak tool is not visible. I've also discovered that under ~/.local/share I have no gnome-shell folder (nor anything similarly named).

When I try to instead use `chrome-gnome-shell`,  https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/ reports 'Unable to locate GNOME Shell settings or version. Make sure it is installed and running.

My shell version is 3.18.5
I am currently running Ubuntu 16.04 on a razer blade.

Comment: Which web browser are you trying? Is it updated?

Comment: Another user had the same issue here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1020702/extensions-missing-from-tweak-toll-menu, however also there no solution emerged.

Comment: All right, no answer was given in the other post because the user apparently was on Unity and not in a gnome session. So please, although it appears so,  check that you are effectively on gnome shell with the output of the commands `echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` and `wmctrl -m`

Comment: I tried on Firefox (the only browser I have installed at the moment) and as far as I know it is fully updated. 
I tried both commands, and neither were recognized - they just returned errors.
```gnome-shell --version``` returns ```GNOME Shell 3.18.5```. Does that help?