# Gnome tweaks extension tab missing

Tags: gnome-shell-extension, gnome-tweaks

I installed gnome tweaks with
`sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`
Then it doesnt show the extensions tab.
I reinstalled it but no use I watched numerous YouTube tutorial so see wether it's a mistake in installation still didn't get it.

Pls help.
Thanks in Advance.

Edit
I tried to run gnome tweaks using terminal and there is this error.
[Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1arS.png)

the error of *file line number 216
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZKTh.png)

AskUbuntu is not letting me use Embedded images so dont worry of the link.

Comment: please edit your question with the version of ubuntu are you using and the computer model.

Comment: I'm using a laptop
Ubuntu 18.04 dual boot with windows 10

Comment: What are the outputs of these commands taken from this source : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056583/gnome-shell-extensions-not-installing-properly  `echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP`  and `gnome-shell --version`  ?

Comment: echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP gives-:
GNOME-Flashback:GNOME
gnome-shell --version gives
3.28.3

Comment: I found this posted in another answer with the same problem: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1369268/ubuntu-21-10-upgrade-went-without-a-glitch-except-gnome, here's the answer provided: https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/05/gnome-tweaks-40-no-longer-manage-extensions/

Comment: Thank you
But I deleted python thinking it made the error now I can't login can you please tell me how to connect to the internet on recovery mode without the iconfig code .

Comment: I suspect you really broke your computer.  Deleting python, to my knowledge will NEVER fix anything.  Python is basic/native/innate to linux/ubuntu functionality, as you can see now.  What computer are using?  Are you able to get into recovery mode?  If so what options are available?  Do you have/can you create a live USB/disk?  Other than that I'm not sure if there's a way to recover from such a deletion.

Comment: This is what python is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)

Comment: Thank you tbr for you help but it's not a problem I successfully formatted my pc luckily I had a backup and live usb for multi booting windows and Linux.                        I wanted to vote you but I cannot a heartly thank you for you mind to help